# Testing tensorflow-hub installation: universal sentence encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I would like to try universal sentence encoder from here [link](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2)

Here is my code running on Ubuntu 18.04 and Jupyter Notebook

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
embeddings = embed([
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    "I am a sentence for which I would like to get its embedding"])

print(session.run(embeddings))
```

It just keeps running and nothing happening. Is it downloading something? I have been waiting for quite some time. It is not displaying anything beyond the following:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0517 09:23:47.724080 139743818422080 __init__.py:56] Some hub symbols are not available because TensorFlow version is less than 1.14
```

I checked my tensorflow installation. It looks fine.
Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are fine. This error message talks about symbols that matter only for using TF Hub in TensorFlow 2, notably hub.KerasLayer. The established TF1.x usage works just fine.

Code has already been submitted (but not picked up by a regular Hub release yet) to switch to a less alarming wording. Sorry for the confusion.